# Как задать цвет контура в кнопке?

Tags: java, android

Как задать цвет контура в кнопке?

Сейчас есть ImageButton, c картинкой всредине, как задать цвет контура синим?

Нужно что бы кнопка выглядела так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выберите для ImageView Background с контуром

```
<stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#369"/>
```

а как `SRC` (source) самолетик

Answer (score 2):

параметр `stroke` дает вам `border`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#00FF00"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

`